# Choosing pandas function based on variable passed to a function

Tags: pandas, python-3.8

I have the following code which I am trying to generalize:

```
    def Fn():
        gt75 = itemConst.groupby(['val1', 'val2'])['cumImpa'].shift(fill_value=0).gt(0.75)]
```

My usage however can be very varied and I might end up using `lt` or `le` etc.

Is it possible to have a generalized function as follows:

```
    def Fn(funcIn):
        gt75 = itemConst.groupby(['val1', 'val2'])['cumImpa'].shift(fill_value=0).funcIn(0.75)]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try:

```
ne = pd.Series.ne  # or pd.DataFrame.ne
eq = pd.Series.eq  # or pd.DataFrame.eq
le = pd.Series.le  # ...
lt = pd.Series.lt  # itemConst['cumpImpa'] is a Series
ge = pd.Series.ge
gt = pd.Series.gt


def binop(op, val):
    return op(itemConst.groupby(['val1', 'val2'])['cumImpa'].shift(fill_value=0), val)

mask = binop(gt, 0.75)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can provide the function name as a string, you can use [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr). `getattr` returns an attribute of an object by name.

Something like this:

```
def Fn(funcIn):
    foo = itemConst.groupby(['val1', 'val2'])['cumImpa'].shift(fill_value=0)
    gt75 = getattr(foo, funcIn)(0.75)
```

And then call it as `Fn('gt')` etc.